# mysqli_fetch_assoc dies on first row

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following table in MySQL:

╔══════╦════╗
║... City.....║...ZIP..║
╠══════╬════╣
║ Prague. ║ 11000║
║ Brno.....   ║ 34785║
╚═══════════╝

The following code works:

```
Class Mysql{
  function connect(){
    $this->c = new mysqli(
      $this->OPTION['dbhost'],
      $this->OPTION['dbuser'],
      $this->OPTION['dbpass'],
      $this->OPTION['dbname']
    );
    if($this->c->connect_errno){
      exit("Connect failed: ".$this->c->connect_error);
    }
    if(!$this->c->select_db($this->OPTION['dbname'])){
      exit("Cannot select the database: ".$this->OPTION['dbname']);
    }
  }
  function query($query){
    if(!$this->c->query($query)){
      exit("Cannot execute the query: {$query}<br>MySQL Error: {$this->c->error}<br>MySQL Error Code: {$this->c->errno}");
    }
    return $this->c->query($query);
  }
  function fetch_assoc($result){
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
  }
}

$DB = new Mysql;
$DB->connect();
$query = $DB->query("SELECT city, ZIP FROM cities");
while($row = $DB->fetch_assoc()){
  print_r($row);
}
```

The code works until I try to change fetch_assoc part like this:

```
  function fetch_assoc($query){
    $result = $this->query($query);
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
  }
}

$DB = new Mysql;
$DB->connect();
while($row = $DB->fetch_assoc("SELECT city, ZIP FROM cities")){
  print_r($row);
}
```

In this case it endlessly (stopped by max execution time) prints the first row of the table:
Array ( [City] => Prague [ZIP] => 11000 )

Comment: +1 for the sexy table formatting :P

Comment: Your while loop is calling `$DB->fetch_assoc()` every iteration and that function makes a new query. You should be getting `$result` once and do the equivalent of `$result->fetch_assoc()` in the while loop

Comment: If my above comment was not clear, every time the while loop runs you are making the query `"SELECT city, ZIP FROM cities"` and it is returning the first result of that query. You only want to make that query once

Comment: More than clear, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it, it would be making the query once and iterating over it as mentioned in my comments above:

```
$DB = new Mysql;
$DB->connect();
$query = $DB->query("SELECT city, ZIP FROM cities");
$result = $DB->fetch_assoc();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) print_r($row);
```

Comment: Gah… I can barely read it, ha ha. It looks like you are returning the entire result which should work

Comment: Sorry, can edit like that only :( I went for the following solution:  

`function fetch_assoc($query){  

$result = $this->query($query);  

$array = array();  

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  

array_push($array,$row);  

}  

return $array;  

}`  

And  

`$DB = new Mysql;  

$DB->connect();  

$row = $DB->fetch_assoc("SELECT module, folder FROM rdp_modules");  

print_r($row);`  

As I expected, it creates a 3D array and prints:  

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [City] => Prague [ZIP] => 11000 ) [1] => Array ( [City] => Brno [ZIP] => 34785 ) )`